# How can I set the constructor using composition

Tags: composition

When I have 2 classes and I want to use composition like that:

```
 class A {
    B beans
    }
```

How can I set default values to B? And can I initialize it in A's constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the language I suppose.

The general rule of the thumb is that the constructor needs to create the object and make sure it is in a valid state. So if in your case a valid state depends on whether or not the B class is initialised you can call the constructor of B. This will make sure that your class A whenever it is used is in a valid state and ready to use.

To get back on your question, yes you can assign a default value to B depending on the language.

Hope this helps.

Comment: and if beans is a pointer of type B or a vector, what is the case here?

Comment: Depends if your class A really needs that. Since it is composition I kinda assume that class A is doing something with beans. The thing is you can leave it but in general if A contains public methods that require B to be initialised you want to make sure that B is in a  valid state